# TeamCity Unmet requirements: MSBuildTools14.0_x86_Path exists

Tags: build, teamcity

I have a solution built in VS 2015 and need to set up TeamCity to run it.

I have installed a build agent on a Virtual Machine, but TeamCity marks all the build profiles for this build agent as incompatible and gives the following error:

**Unmet requirements: 
MSBuildTools14.0_x86_Path exists**

I have installed MSBuild Tools 2013. Please advise what to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You need to download Microsoft Build Tools 2015 from this link -https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159 and make sure path is added in System Variable

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I used chocolatey tool to install MSBuild Tools packages. It installed the latest version for VS 2017, but my solution was built in VS 2015. So I uninstalled the package and then installed again. It resolved the problem.